# installing operating system with external cd rom

Tags: boot

I have a  dell desk top .I installed a new hard drive and my cd rom doesn't work.using an external cd rom couldnt install operating system . what is the order of booting the system?

Comment: How is the external CD drive connected to the computer?

Comment: Use a bootable USB instead of external CD ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern Dell computers will give you a boot menu when you press <kbd>F12</kbd> during the computer start up.  You would select "Boot from USB CDROM" or something similar.  You might have to go into BIOS setup by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> to change the boot order settings.

If you are still having issue, remove the cables from your old CDROM drive.  It is possible, yet unlikely if might still be trying to boot from it.

All of this is assuming your computer actually supports booting from USB devices.  I havent seen a modern Dell PC without the ability in many years, but if your computer is really old, it might not.